# How can I run a JavaScript function at specified times of the day?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to run a function every 16 minutes but not when user goes to page, rather at a specific time.

For example: 12:01, 12:16, 12:31, 12:46, 13:01, 13:16, 13:31 and so on...

How do I do that?

```
updateTodayCharts = setInterval(function () {
    ajax_update( date1 , date2 );
}, 15 * 60 * 1000);
```

This script runs `ajax_update` every 15 minutes. When you visit the page at 12:20 it runs at 12:35 (12:20 + 15 minutes).

I need to run this script at 12:36 (so after 11 minutes not 15)

First i will calculate time from now to next update and then set timeinterval time.

Comment: Do you know how to use the Date object? Use a little Match and determine the time length you need to set to get to the next 16.

Comment: aaahh right :d i didn't think about it. thx

Comment: Could you translate the title of your question?

Comment: Make a function to check the time, preferably the server because users can be in different time zones.

Comment: Your time intervals are 15 minutes, not 16

Comment: I know, that's an example

Comment: What shell happen if the user visits that page before 12:01? Or is there no specific start of the sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, one is to store last date, have a shorter interval and check enough time has passed, the other is to combine *setTimeout* with *setInterval*, or some similar such construction.

```
var interval = (new Date().getUTCMinutes() + 59) % 15; // current position
interval = 15 - interval;   // remaining til next position
interval = interval * 60e3; // to ms

interval = window.setTimeout(function () {
    interval = window.setInterval(function () {
        ajax_update( date1 , date2 );
    }, 15 * 60e3);
}, interval);
```

Comment: After a bit of thinking I came to the solution that the offset till next 1, 16, ... must be calculated then a setTimeout followed by a setInterval bu you already did it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check each minute if the number of minutes is 1, 16, 31, 46 or whatever you want but in this case number of minutes modulo 15 must be equal to one :

```
updateTodayCharts = setInterval(function () {
    var d = new Date(),
        min = d.getMinutes();
    if (min % 15 === 1) ajax_update( date1 , date2 );
}, 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: _setInterval_ is not guaranteed to happen at exactly the provided ms, what happens if it falls just short?

Comment: Then it would be just in the next minute don't you think?

Comment: I meant more like, what happens if it happens first time at say `12:01:00.002`, then the interval takes `59997` ms, instead of `60000`?

Comment: That's a good question, then the setInterval function we have will need a bit of tuning. But let's first see if it does meet the requirements as it is now.

Comment: I just wrote this short bit of code to observe error in _setInterval_ over 2 second intervals; `var then = Date.now(), delta = 0, int = window.setInterval(function () {
    var now = Date.now(),
        d = now - then - 2e3;
    then = now;
    delta += Math.abs(d);
    console.log(delta, d);
}, 2e3);`